# Can this OAuth2 Native app flow be considered secure?

Tags: security, mobile, oauth, openid-connect

I have an OpenID Connect provider built with IdentityServer4 and ASP.NET Identity, running on let's say: `login.example.com`.

I have a SPA application running on let's say `spa.example.com`, that already uses my OpenID Connect provider to authenticate users through `login.example.com` and authorize them to access the SPA.

I have a mobile app (native on both platforms) that is using a custom authentication system at the moment.

I thought it would be nice to get rid of the custom auth system, and instead allow my users to log-in with the same account they use on the SPA, by using my OpenID provider.

So I started by looking on the OpenID connect website and also re-reading the [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749), after a few google searches I realized that was a common problem and I found [RFC8252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252) (OAuth2 for Native clients), also Client Dynamic Registration ([RFC7591](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7591)) and PKCE ([RFC7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636)).

I scratched my head about the fact that it was no longer possible to store any kind of "secret" on the client/third-party (the native apps) as it could become compromised.

I disscussed the topic with some co-workers and we came out with the following set-up:

1. Associate a domain let's say `app.example.com` to my mobile app by using Apple [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/) and Android [App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations).
2. Use an AuthenticationCode flow for both clients and enforce them to use PKCE.
3. Use a `redirect_uri` on the app associated domain say: `https://app.example.com/openid`
4. Make the user always consent to log-in into the application after log-in, because neither iOS or Android would bring back the application by doing an automatic redirect, it has to be the user who manually clicks the universal/app link every time.

I used AppAuth library on both apps and everything is working just fine right now on *test*, but I'm wondering:

1. Do you think this is a secure way to prevent that anyone with the right skills could impersonate my apps or by any other means get unauthorized access to my APIs? What is the current best practice on achieving this?
2. Is there any way to avoid having the user to always "consent" (having them to actually tap the universal/app link).
3. I also noted that Facebook uses their application as a kind of authorization server itself, so when I tap "sing-in with facebook" on an application I get to a facebook page that asks me if I would like to" launch the application to perform log-in". I would like to know how can I achieve something like this, to allow my users login to the SPA on a phone by using my application if installed, as facebook does with theirs.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I thought it would be nice to get rid of the custom auth system, and instead allow my users to log-in with the same account they use on the SPA, by using my OpenID provider.**

This is what OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect provides you. The ability to use single user identity among different services. So this is the correct approach .!

**it was no longer possible to store any kind of "secret" on the client/third-party (the native apps) as it could become compromised**

Correct. From OAuth 2.0 specification perspective, these are called **[public clients](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1)**. They are not recommended to have client secrets associated to them. Instead, authorization code, application ID and Redirect URL is used to validate token request in identity provider. This makes authorization code a valuable secret.!

**Associate a domain let's say app.example.com to my mobile app by using Apple Universal Links and Android App Links.**

Not a mobile expert. But yes, custom URL domains are the way to handle redirect for OAuth and OpenID Connect.

Also usage of PKCE is the correct approach. Hence redirect occur in the browser (user agent) there can be malicious parties which can obtain the authorization code. PKCE avoid this by introducing a secret that will not get exposed to user agent (browser). Secret is only used in token request (direct HTTP communication) thus is secure.

**Q1**

Using authorization code flow with PKCE is a standard best practice recommended by OAuth specifications. This is valid for OpenID Connect as well (hence it's built on OAuth 2.0)

One thing to note is that, if you believe PKCE secret can be exploited, then it literally means device is compromised. Think about extracting secret from OS memory. that means system is compromised (virus/ keylogger or  what ever we call them). In such case end user and your application has more things to be worried about.

Also, I believe this is for a business application. If that's the case your clients will definitely have security best practice guide for their devices. For example installation of virus guards and restrictions of application installation. To prevent attacks mentioned above, we will have to rely on such security establishments. OAuth 2.0 alone is not secure .!  Thats's why there are best practice guides([RFC68129](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819)) and policies.

**Q2**

Not clear on this. Consent page is presented from Identity Provider. So it will be a configuration of that system.

**Q3**

Well, Identity Provider can maintain a SSO session in the browser. Login page is present on that browser. So most of the time, if app uses the same browser, users should be able to use SPA without a login.

Answer (score 1):

The threat here comes from someone actually installing a malicious app on their device that could indeed impersonate your app. PKCE prevents another app from intercepting legitimate sign in requests initiated from your app so the standard approach is about as safe as you can make it. Forcing the user to sign in/consent every time should help a bit to make them take note of what is going on.

From a UX PoV I think it makes a lot of sense to minimize the occasions when the browser-based sign in flow is used. I'd leverage the security features of the platform (e.g. secure enclave on iOS) and keep a refresh token in there once the user has signed in interactively and then they can sign in using their PIN, finger print or face etc.

Comment: Yeah that’s definitely how I’m going to do it, the user will be doing the described flow just the first time, or after an update. Please explain how someone could impersonate my application if the redirect uri is an Universal Link that could only be recieved by my application.

Comment: If the OS can guarantee that only your app will receive the callback then you probably don’t need to worry. I was thinking along the lines of custom url schemes which could potentially have the impersonation problem

Comment: That’s why we choose to force the redirect_uri to be an actual webpage which is linked to the app in a way that supposedly can’t be impersonated